# Replacing some characters in a string with another character

Tags: string, bash

I have a string like `AxxBCyyyDEFzzLMN` and I want to replace all the occurrences of `x`, `y`, and `z` with `_`.

How can I achieve this?

I know that `echo "$string" | tr 'x' '_' | tr 'y' '_'` would work, but I want to do that in one go, without using pipes.

Comment: Did you want to replace any sequence of consecutive x's, y's or z's with _one_ underscore, or did you want to replace _each_ x, y, or z with one underscore? Also, what about mixed sequences, like `AxyzB`? Three underscores or one?

Comment: `tr '[xyz]'` will replace `[` and `]`, too. The argument should be simply a list of characters (though ranges like `a-z` are okay, and in some implementations, POSIX character classes like `[:digit:]`).

Answer (score 550, accepted):

```
echo "$string" | tr xyz _
```

would replace each occurrence of `x`, `y`, or `z` with `_`, giving `A__BC___DEF__LMN` in your example.

```
echo "$string" | sed -r 's/[xyz]+/_/g'
```

would replace repeating occurrences of `x`, `y`, or `z` with a single `_`, giving `A_BC_DEF_LMN` in your example.

Comment: On Mac, I got the following:
sed: illegal option -- r
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]

Comment: I have a string that contains `,[]{}()~` characters.
I want to replace it with each special character escaped with `'\'`
how could I get this done by oneshot?

Comment: @halakala Mac ships with a slightly different version of sed. See this question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13711/differences-between-sed-on-mac-osx-and-other-standard-sed  Instead you can install "gnu-sed" with Homebrew package manager then use the `gsed` binary: `$ brew install gnu-sed` then `$ gsed -r 's/[xyz]+/_/g'`

Comment: On *BSD (and thus, OSX), `sed -E` is (basically) equivalent to `sed -r` on many Linux distros,  If you use `sed 's/[xyz][xyz]*/_/g'` you don't need the option.  Of course, this is equivalent to `tr -s xyz _` so no real need for `sed` here.

Comment: @inckka You can't use `tr` for that.  `sed 's/[][{}()~,]/\\&/g'` but really, ask a new question if you have a follow-up question (feel free to link back here for reference, of course).  Incidentally, `,` and `~` are not regex metacharacters (though `~` gets expanded to `$HOME` in some positions by Bash and some other shells; not `sh` however).

Comment: @iOSdev You can use character ranges instead for non-GNU sed: `echo "abcddefg" | sed 's/[def]\{1,\}/_/g'` is equivalent to the functionality in the answer.

Comment: @DisplayName had the same issue when i called `tr -. _`. '-' was seen as a prefix for a command option. changing the order of characters fixed the issue: `tr .- _`

Answer (score 418):

Using [Bash Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
orig="AxxBCyyyDEFzzLMN"
mod=${orig//[xyz]/_}
```

Comment: @Alexey, my example works for me (bash 4.3.11(1)-release).  Make sure you are using `bash`.  Other shells might not work (though some will).

Comment: Thank you @MatthewFlaschen . This was exactly what I needed to do a sed replace for an absolute path in a bash script (replacing the / with \/ so sed accepts it).

Comment: @RyanG why use `sed` if bash has built-in substitution?

Comment: @MestreLion That may have come out wrong, but I needed to replace a standard variable name in a bunch of files with an absolute path, for which i was using sed inplace replacement. but you cant have "/" without escaping it in the command. I was stringing the operations together in bash. Would this not be the best way to manipulate a string in bash?

Comment: @RyanG sed accepts any char as separator for `s`. Since you're dealing with paths, that usually contain many `/`, it might be easier (and more readable) to do `sed 's#/some/path#/some/other/path#'` than doing lots of escaping

Comment: @RyanG and yes, your approach seems good, but it has little to do with *bash*  string substitution. Also, you might consider `awk -v` when dealing with arbitrary pathnames, as no matter what separator you choose there's always the risk a given file will contain that char, which would break `sed`

Answer (score 220):

You might find this link helpful:
http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html.

In general, to replace the first match of `$substring` with `$replacement`:

```bash
${string/substring/replacement}
```

To replace all matches of `$substring` with `$replacement`:

```
${string//substring/replacement}
```

EDIT:
Note that this applies to a variable named `$string`.

Comment: Note that this works on a **variable named "string"** not on the literal string.

Comment: the most helpfull, since it contains reference.

Comment: This also works when using empty replacement (removing matches from string). `tr`, which is mentioned in another answers, requires replacement string to be provided.

Answer (score 15):

Here is a solution with shell parameter expansion that replaces multiple contiguous occurrences with a single `_`:

```
$ var=AxxBCyyyDEFzzLMN
$ echo "${var//+([xyz])/_}"
A_BC_DEF_LMN
```

Notice that the `+(pattern)` pattern requires extended pattern matching, turned on with

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Alternatively, with the `-s` ("squeeze") option of `tr`:

```
$ tr -s xyz _ <<< "$var"
A_BC_DEF_LMN
```

Answer (score 9):

```
read filename ;
sed -i 's/letter/newletter/g' "$filename" #letter
```

^use as many of these as you need, and you can make your own BASIC encryption

Answer (score 2):

```bash
echo 'I dont like PHP' |  sed -r 's/I dont like/I love/g'
## Output: I love PHP
```

OR

```bash
echo 'I like PHP' |  sed -r 's/like/love/g' 
## Output: I love PHP
```

Comment: The question says "I want to replace all the occurrences of `x`, `y`, and `z` with `_`". The top answer already covers a decent `sed` answer and addresses the question. Can you explain what this answer adds exactly?