# Split a string based on backslash delimiter

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I'm new to bash scripting. I have a string which is like so: `\\abc\def\ghi`

I want to parse the string using a delimiter and need a one line command for converting it to `/abc/def/ghi` (convert Windows path to unix path).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871181/bash-string-replacing-a-some-char-with-another

Comment: by the way, such a conversion won't change windows path to a unix one. example: C:\WINDOWS -> C:/WINDOWS

Answer (score 3):

Try doing this :

```
$ x='\abc\def\ghi'
$ echo ${x//\\//}
/abc/def/ghi
```

See [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe)

**NOTE**

- *parameter expansions* are [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) built-ins, so it's quicker than external commands

Answer (score 0):

```
string=$( echo "$string" | tr '\' '/' )
```

Answer (score 0):

or with sed:

```
kent$  echo -E "\abc\def\ghi"|sed 's:\\:/:g' 
/abc/def/ghi
```