# Remove double quotes from txt file

Tags: shell

I have a file that contains unwanted double quotes around the column values. I need to remove them. Could someone help me on this?

The data is in below format

`column1   date        picture      value`

`"A"    "2016-06-02"    "books"      932422
"B"    "2016-06-03"    "movies"     934735
"C"    "2016-06-04"    "vidoes"     936025
"D"    "2016-06-05"    "movies"     937620
"E"    "2016-06-06"    "dvd"        938972
"F"    "2016-06-07"    "vidoes"     940274`

And I want to the data to be like:

`column1 date  picture      value`

`A   2016-06-02    books      932422
B   2016-06-03    movies     934735
C   2016-06-04    vidoes     936025
D   2016-06-05    movies     937620
E   2016-06-06    dvd        938972
F   2016-06-07    vidoes     940274`

Note that 4th column attribute do not have double quotes around them.

Could somebody help me with removing these double quotes with one line shell scripting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash string replacing some chars with another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871181/bash-string-replacing-some-chars-with-another)

Comment: Several exact duplicates on Unix SE

Answer (score 3):

```
 tr -d '"' <infile
column1   date        picture      value
A    2016-06-02    books      932422
B    2016-06-03    movies     934735
C    2016-06-04    vidoes     936025
D    2016-06-05    movies     937620
E    2016-06-06    dvd        938972
F    2016-06-07    vidoes     940274
```

Or using `awk` :

```
awk -F\" '{$1=$1}1' infile
column1   date        picture      value
 A      2016-06-02      books       932422
 B      2016-06-03      movies      934735
 C      2016-06-04      vidoes      936025
 D      2016-06-05      movies      937620
 E      2016-06-06      dvd         938972
 F      2016-06-07      vidoes      940274
```

or using `sed` :

```
 sed 's/"//g' infile
column1   date        picture      value
A    2016-06-02    books      932422
B    2016-06-03    movies     934735
C    2016-06-04    vidoes     936025
D    2016-06-05    movies     937620
E    2016-06-06    dvd        938972
F    2016-06-07    vidoes     940274
```

or using `awk`'s `gsub` function:

```
awk '{gsub(/"/,"")}1' infile
column1   date        picture      value
A    2016-06-02    books      932422
B    2016-06-03    movies     934735
C    2016-06-04    vidoes     936025
D    2016-06-05    movies     937620
E    2016-06-06    dvd        938972
F    2016-06-07    vidoes     940274
```

Comment: great! for your quick response. I also actually figured out the solution using sed and it worked. However, having diff soln from your end is helpful

Answer (score 0):

If you can use sed,

```
$ sed 's/\"//g' file.txt > file_new.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the below command and run it on the file. The file gets modified automatically. No need for a temporary file for redirection.

```
 perl -pi -e 's/\"//g' infile
```