# removing string from filename

Tags: regex, rename

I know this is simple but I am having a hell of a time with it. I tried `mv` I tried `rename` but I can't get it to work for some reason even after looking at examples and I don't want to spend an hour or more on something that should be simple. I just need to remove a string from a filename, if the string is found. It will be part of a bash script that receives the filename as an argument to $1. I just need to stip `[test]` from the filename. So if I run the command `file_rename.sh myfile[test].txt` it renames `myfile[test].txt` to `myfile.txt`.

Comment: this ought be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871181/bash-string-replacing-some-chars-with-another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working

rename 's/\[test]//' myfile[test].txt