# CSV separated by space to separated by comma in terminal

Tags: csv, awk, terminal, grep

I have a CSV file like this:

```
$ head file.csv 
22.87333333 22.87333333
22.87944444 89.84361111
22.89722222 89.8425
```

I want to transfer it to comma separated using terminal. Like this;

```
$ head file.csv 
22.87333333,22.87333333
22.87944444,89.84361111
22.89722222,89.8425
```

What are the ways of doing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing some characters in a string with another character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871181/replacing-some-characters-in-a-string-with-another-character)

Comment: What did you try for yourself? Show us the efforts even if they are resourceful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sed has a transliteration command, `y`:

```
$ sed 'y/ /,/' file.csv
22.87333333,22.87333333
22.87944444,89.84361111
22.89722222,89.8425
```

Answer (score 3):

And an **awk** solution as well:

```
$ awk -v OFS=',' '{$1=$1}1' file.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use **tr** (translate) command

```
tr " " "," <file
```

**awk** equivalent

```
$ awk '{OFS=","; $1=$1}1' file
```

**Output:**

```
22.87333333,22.87333333
22.87944444,89.84361111
22.89722222,89.8425
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your file is actually space-separated values, this `sed` command:

```
$ sed -i 's/ /,/g' file.csv
```

will inplace (`-i`) replace each occurrence (`g`lobally) of space with comma, using the [`s`substitute command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command).