# Replace comma and newline with sed

Tags: sed

I hope to replace comma and newline with sed.

But, it is failed.

```
sed 's/,\n/\n/g'
```

How do I do it?

Example:

```
asdf,

asdf,

asdf,
```

=>

```
asdf

asdf

asdf
```

Comment: A little searching goes a long way... [Replacing some characters in a string with another character](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2871181/608639), [
Using sed to replace special characters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/212925/56041), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you also want to remove the lines not ending with a comma.

```
sed -n 's/,$//p'
```

No print by default `-n`, print if substitution was made with `p` command at the end.

The `g` flag is not necessary, there is only one substitution per line.