# Write an equivalent GNU/Linux command

Tags: python, linux, command-line

How can I write an equivalent GNU/Linux command which gives the same output as the script? The input to the command should be the same as the variable var1 in the following script.

```
#!/bin/python
my_char = { 'a':'b', 'b':'c', 'c':'d'}
var1 = "abc"
var2 = ""
for ch in var1:
   if ch in my_char:
     var2+=my_char[ch]
   else:
     var2+=ch
 print var2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing some characters in a string with another character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871181/replacing-some-characters-in-a-string-with-another-character)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`tr`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr_(Unix)) command:

```
echo abc | tr abc bcd
```

This outputs:

```
bcd
```