# Special character Replace ' character with \" characters in shell scripting

Tags: shell, unix

I have a string

```
str="this is 'the string' example"
```

I want to replace special character `'` character with a special charecter `\"` character. And finally

```
str= "this is \"the string\" example"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871181/replacing-some-characters-in-a-string-with-another-character

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace one substring for another string in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210880/replace-one-substring-for-another-string-in-shell-script)

Comment: Some clues as well in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210880/replace-one-substring-for-another-string-in-shell-script