# How to replace string in expression with GitHub actions

Tags: github-actions

This is my action that returns `$TOXENV` that looks like this `py3.6-django2.2` I'd like to `$TOXENV` to look like this instead `py36-django22` is there any substitute/replace function that I could use to replace `.` char?

```yaml
name: CI
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    branches: [ master, actions ]
jobs:
  demo:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        python: [3.6, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9]
        django: ['2.2', '3.0']
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python }} ${{ matrix.django }}
        with:
          python-version: ${{ matrix.python }}
      - name: python version
        env:
            TOXENV: "py${{ matrix.python }}-django${{ matrix.django }}"
        run:
          echo $TOXENV
```

Comment: You could use what is suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871181/replacing-some-characters-in-a-string-with-another-character on your `run` last step to substitute the `.` for something else.

Comment: Thanks. That is a general substitution with `sed` but is there any build in function for GitHub Actions ?

Answer (score 12):

Another way by using BASH native [variable substitution](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html):

```
  - name: python version
    env:
        TOXENV: "py${{ matrix.python }}-django${{ matrix.django }}"
    run: |
      TOXENV=${{ env.TOXENV }}
      TOXENV=${TOXENV//.} # replace all dots
      echo TOXENV=${TOXENV} >> $GITHUB_ENV # update GitHub ENV vars
  - name: print env
    run: echo ${{ env.TOXENV }}
```

The idea is to read the GitHub actions expression variable into a BASH variable and do the string manipulation then export or set-output to update in GitHub actions runtime.

Comment: Work perfectly. Even as a one liner: `run: echo "TOXENV=${BRANCH/\//-}" >> $GITHUB_ENV`. Changes slashes into dashes.

Answer (score 11):

I don't think there's an easy way to do this in the `env` directive of your step when defining the value of TOXENV. The `env` directive accepts expressions, but the [functions that can be used in expressions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#functions) are limited, with nothing that can replace arbitrary characters. The closest I could find is [`format()`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#format), but that unfortunately requires numbered braces in the target string, which won't work for your situation.

Instead, perhaps you could set the value of TOXENV in the `run` directive using `sed`, then [add it to the environment](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable):

```yaml
      - name: python version
        run:
          RAW_TOXENV="py${{ matrix.python }}-django${{ matrix.django }}"
          TOXENV=$(echo $RAW_TOXENV | sed 's/\.//')
          echo "TOXENV=$TOXENV" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

Comment: I up vote the answer. It's a pity that for the moment (25 April 2021) functions doesn't include replace directive/function. Moving replace logic to run is at the moment only one solution.

Comment: It's March 2022 and we still don't have a native string replace function available.