# Do I need quotes to substitute Github workflow substitution in string?

Tags: github, github-actions

I defined the input to a Github workflow action like so. To create the string values, I enclose the substitution in double-quotes, to follow how it would be in Bash:

```
 uses: dmnemec/copy_file_to_another_repo_action@v1.0.4
    env:
      API_TOKEN_GITHUB: ${{ secrets.GH_API_TOKEN }}
    with:
      source_file: "${{ steps.create-copy-file.outputs.filename }}.yaml"
      destination_repo: "${{ github.repository_owner }}/repo"
      destination_folder: "releases/${{ steps.create-copy-file.outputs.target_folder }}"
      user_email: "user@mail.com"
      user_name: "User Name"
```

However, [examples in Github](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions) shows that I can substitute for the value without needing to enclose it in quotes. I tried defining the values above without quotes and they seem to work i.e. the file is copied correctly to the target repo and folder.

```
 uses: dmnemec/copy_file_to_another_repo_action@v1.0.4
    env:
      API_TOKEN_GITHUB: ${{ secrets.GH_API_TOKEN }}
    with:
      source_file: ${{ steps.create-copy-file.outputs.filename }}.yaml
      destination_repo: ${{ github.repository_owner }}/repo
      destination_folder: releases/${{ steps.create-copy-file.outputs.target_folder }}
      user_email: user@mail.com
      user_name: "User Name"
```

I tried looking for examples in Github to know whether this practice is allowed or suggested but couldn't find any. The one example I have found is from this Azure developer page (example no.6): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/github/github-variable-substitution.

[Another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67231657/how-to-replace-string-in-expression-with-github-actions), wraps the string in double quotes.

My question is, is it necessary to enclose string substitution in Github workflow in single/double quotes? Is this an officially supported feature or an unintended feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, generally you do not need quotes. The workflow file is YAML and this is all about quotes in YAML:

[YAML: Do I need quotes for strings in YAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19109912/yaml-do-i-need-quotes-for-strings-in-yaml)

Comment: Note that GitHub workflow expressions have their own rules for quotes beyond what's required YAML syntax. https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions