# how to use sed to replace all backslashes with double quote?

Tags: sed, replace, double-quotes, backslash

I am trying to use this to replace all backslashes with double quotes.

```bash
sed -e "s/'\\\\''/\"/g" nomefile
```

this doesn't do anything.

Input: `"prova d\"amico"`

Desired output: `"prova d""amico"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacing some characters in a string with another character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871181/replacing-some-characters-in-a-string-with-another-character)

Comment: Your `sed` code is not looking for backslashes. It's looking for backslashes surrounded by single quotes, and followed by a second single quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -e 's/\\/"/g'
```

Will replace all `/` with `"`

---

Your issue is in the first part: `\\\''/`, you're looking for `'` surrounded `/`, but you just need `\\` for an escaped `\`

---

```
➜ cat input
"prova d\"amico"
➜ 
➜ sed -e 's/\\/"/g' input
"prova d""amico"
➜
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a command specifically for global character substitutions ("transliterations"), [`y`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-y-_0028transliterate_0029-command):

```bash
sed 'y/\\/"/'
```

where `\` has to be escaped with another `\`.