# create a comma separated string from space separated var value in bash

Tags: bash, git-bash

Team, converting a bash array var to a string or list that is comma separated so that i can use the entire var at a place in a function.

I have a var which has output of `git diff @ @~1 --name-only`

var1=$(git diff @ @~1 --name-only)
echo $var

```
file1
file2
filex
```

what i want is with a comma.
echo $var
`file1,file2,filex`

i tried below but no luck

echo $var | sed 's/ /,/g'

```
file1
file2
filex
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacing some characters in a string with another character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871181/replacing-some-characters-in-a-string-with-another-character)

Comment: i tried the accepted sol and it did not. may be am trying wrong? `echo $var3 | tr  ,`

Comment: The proper syntax for that is `tr '\n' ,`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `awk` to your command like this:

```
$ var=$(git diff @ @~1 --name-only | awk '{printf "%s,", $1}')
$ echo $var
file1,file2,filex,
```

And to remove last coma use this:

```
$ echo ${var%,}
file1,file2,filex
```

Answer (score 3):

You appear to want to replace linefeeds with commas:

```
tr '\n' ',' <<< "$var"
```

Comment: how to strip the last comma that am seeing with your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot understand your question well, but if you want to replace an string in the bash commands, you can use this example:

```
VAR="f1 f2 f3"
echo ${VAR}
echo "$VAR" | sed -r 's/[ ]+/,/g'
```

I hope it works.

Comment: I cannot edit my answer. I cannot improve my answer anymore. :)

Comment: can you specify how to get this to work on mac? it fails `sed: illegal option -- r` though i need answer for unix and mac